# jQuery event preventdefault and continue

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-admin

I am currently working on a Django project and am using the Django admin and its jQuery to add a modal between the submit button and the real form submit.

To achieve this I've implemented the following:

```
var submit_form;

django.jQuery('form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        submit_form = this;
        modal.open();
    });
```

and in modal close function I'm using:

```
submit_form.submit();
```

This actually works, but I loose the Django admin functionality of the "Save and add another" and "Save and continue editing" buttons.
They all do now the same action as the default submit button.

The only thing added to the two other submit buttons is a name attribute:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="default" name="_save">
<input type="submit" value="Save and add another" name="_addanother">
<input type="submit" value="Save and continue editing" name="_continue">
```

I did also check into event and used `event.currentTarget.submit();` in modal close function, but this did not actually work either.

Does someone have an idea how to properly prevent default submit and execute it later?

Thanks.

Comment: Try, `submit_form = $(this);`.

Comment: I've changed to `submit_form = django.jQuery(this);` as this is my $ in Django, but it does nothing. The form is no longer submitted.

Comment: I can submit the form using `submit_form.context.submit();` when using `submit_form = django.jQuery(this);`, but also this falls back to the default submit method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out how to do this. I had to add a hidden input to my form including the name from the submit button.

The following is the modified function I use to fill the missing input:

```
django.jQuery('form').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    submit_form = this;
    // Append action as hidden input
    var action = django.jQuery(this).find('input[type=submit]:focus').attr('name');
    var input = django.jQuery('<input>', {
        type: 'hidden',
        name: action
    });
    submit_form.append(input[0]);
    // Release save button
    django.jQuery(':submit').blur();
    // Finally open modal window
    modal.open();
});
```